# Replace black color in bitmap with red

Tags: android

How can I replace the black color in a bitmap with red (or any other color) programmatically in Android (ignoring transparency)? I can replace the white color in the bitmap with a color already but it somehow does not work with black.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Get all the pixels in the bitmap using this:

```
int [] allpixels = new int [myBitmap.getHeight() * myBitmap.getWidth()];

myBitmap.getPixels(allpixels, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight());

for(int i = 0; i < allpixels.length; i++)
{
    if(allpixels[i] == Color.BLACK)
    {
        allpixels[i] = Color.RED;
    }
}

myBitmap.setPixels(allpixels,0,myBitmap.getWidth(),0, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(),myBitmap.getHeight());
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Works great - only, my PNG seem to have some shades of transparency and with this method the graphic still gets a black (or gray) border which also should be replaced with the appropriate shade of red.

Comment: How do you initialize the pixels[]?

Comment: hey @confucius, i have tried solution here. But I want replace the white color with transparent background. solution here works for changing color can i change any color to transparent background. Do you have any clue of it.

Comment: how can i replace using hex string #FFFFFF to #000000

Comment: Remember that your `Bitmap` needs to be `mutable` for `setPixels(...)` not to throw an `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: filling color in whole space in case of png image,not worked perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

**This works for me**

```
    public Bitmap replaceColor(Bitmap src,int fromColor, int targetColor) {
    if(src == null) {
        return null;
    }
    // Source image size
    int width = src.getWidth();
    int height = src.getHeight();
    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    //get pixels
    src.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

    for(int x = 0; x < pixels.length; ++x) {
        pixels[x] = (pixels[x] == fromColor) ? targetColor : pixels[x];
    }
    // create result bitmap output
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, src.getConfig());
    //set pixels
    result.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

    return result;
}
```

**Now set your bit map**

```
replaceColor(bitmapImg,Color.BLACK,Color.GRAY  )
```

**For better view please check this [Link](https://shaikhhamadali.blogspot.com/2013/08/changereplacementremove-pixel-colors-in.html)**

Answer (score 0):

@nids : Have you tried replacing your Color to Color.TRANSPARENT ? That should work...