# How to change black background color of bitmap to transparent?

Tags: android, bitmap

I am creating `Bitmap` using following code:

```
Bitmap bm= Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

But I want to change `Background` color from *black* to *transparent* because I want to use this object in another `Activity` also. I searched a lot but I am unable to find solution.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13):

Of course the Bitmap created in mode ARGB_8888 supports transparency
But the alpha channel is initially filled by 0xff, so bitmap is opaque.
You have to clear the whole bitmap including the alpha channel like this:

```
Canvas c = new Canvas(bm);
c.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR);
```

Answer (score -1):

Bitmap images do not support transparency. You should use a GIF or a PNG.

http://www.gimpchat.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=1290

Comment: GIF is not recommended on android.

Comment: actually i am using PNG. I want to fill color in image thats why converted into bitmap now same image with filled color i want.How i can extract only image without background from bitmap?

Comment: Well, if you are using a Bitmap object you may want to try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237915/replace-black-color-in-bitmap-with-red