# Draw on specific part of Image

Tags: android, canvas

[image]
I want to fill the specific part of the image with certain color.

[image]

In my case I want to fill the A part with green color.

But when I am using canvas in android. It is going to draw color in the area where A is not there

Comment: What's the difference between the area you want to color and the other you dont?

Comment: meaning my A is Yellow in color so whenever i want to color it only yellow part of the A is going to be colored in green not the other part. See the image is square so the transparent part is not being colored

Comment: Does this solution works for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237915/replace-black-color-in-bitmap-with-red

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699810/how-to-change-bitmap-image-color-in-android/31970565

Comment: see the question again i want to do something like this. Please the gif file

Comment: before drawing, you should check if there is some color in that area, or it is transparent.

Comment: Is there any example this you think is useful in this scenario

Comment: what xactly you need an example for? how to check color of pixels before changing it?

Comment: You can map every image, since it will be fixed, easier than filling colors

Comment: my problem is images are dynamic. The images are to be downloaded from api as the game proceed.